# Add separator to string?

Tags: c#

I got here an sample string output in numbers:

> 123456789

But What my goal is to make it like this:

> Format: 123-45-6789

I was able to look for some codes here but they all have a fix interval , which is not fit from what I am making. It is required to make the input format to be like this "123-45-6789" but when saving it is only required 9 characters long because there is a limit to the space where it should be stored so I used this code to met the 9 characters long storation.

```
Input.Text = Input.Text.Trim().Replace("-", string.Empty);
Bio.SetString(UserName, "9Character", Input.Text.Trim());
```

But when displaying it again , it is again required to be on this format , 123-45-6789. Which is my problem.

Comment: Are the separators added to the string by any rule? did you try something? what is your question?

Comment: Explain more about your question. That will help us to give good solution.

Comment: If you don't have a pattern, you can't re-generate it after removing all `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try something like:

```
 string val = "123456789";
 val =  val.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + val.Substring(3, 2) +  "-" + val.Substring(5) ;
```

Here is a working [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QYm956)

Comment: This helps me fix my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

something like,

```
  string number = "123456789";
  var output = Regex.Replace(number,
                         @"^(\d{3})[ -]?(\d{2})[ -]?(\d{4})( x\d+)?",
                         @"$1-$2-$3$4", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

  Console.WriteLine($"formated {output}");
```

output : `formated 123-45-6789`

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Ftdao)